# Get Server error when accessing an address, but no stack trace

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a hybris website with a single mapping. Each time I try to access a particular url:

[image]

Is there any way to debug such an error?

This is the controller of the page:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/cart")
public class CartPageController extends AbstractPageController
{
    private static final String CART_CMS_PAGE = "cartPage";
    private static final Integer DEFAULT_COOKIE_EXPIRY_AGE = 5184000;
    private static final String DEFAULT_CART_IDENTIFIER_COOKIE_NAME = "cart.identifier.cookie.name";
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(CartPageController.class);


    @Resource(name = "cartFacade")
    private CartFacade cartFacade;

    @Resource(name = "userService")
    private UserService userService;

    @Resource(name = "baseStoreService")
    private BaseStoreService baseStoreService;

    @Resource(name = "catalogVersionService")
    private CatalogVersionService catalogVersionService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showCart(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, final Model model)
            throws CMSItemNotFoundException
    {

        CartData cartData = cartFacade.getSessionCartWithEntryOrdering(true);

        final String cartCookieIdentifier = getCartCookieIdentifier();

        if (!cartFacade.hasEntries())
        {
            final String cartId = getCookieValue(request, cartCookieIdentifier);

            final Optional<CartData> cartDataOptional = cartFacade.getCartsForCurrentUser().stream()
                    .filter(c -> c.getCode().equals(cartId)).findFirst();

            if (cartDataOptional.isPresent())
            {
                cartData = cartDataOptional.get();
            }
        }

        setCookieValue(response, cartCookieIdentifier, cartData.getCode());
        model.addAttribute("cart", cartData);

        setupPageModel(model);

        String model1 = getViewForPage(model);

        return model1;

    }

    protected void setupPageModel(Model model) throws CMSItemNotFoundException
    {
        storeCmsPageInModel(model, getContentPageForLabelOrId(CART_CMS_PAGE));
        setUpMetaDataForContentPage(model, getContentPageForLabelOrId(CART_CMS_PAGE));
    }

    protected String getCookieValue(final HttpServletRequest request, final String cookieName)
    {
        return Arrays.stream(request.getCookies())
                .filter(c -> c.getName().equals(cookieName))
                .findFirst()
                .map(Cookie::getValue)
                .orElse(null);
    }

    protected void setCookieValue(final HttpServletResponse response, final String cookieName, final String cookieValue)
    {
        final Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, cookieValue);
        cookie.setMaxAge(DEFAULT_COOKIE_EXPIRY_AGE);

        response.addCookie(cookie);
    }

    protected String getCartCookieIdentifier()
    {
        final String baseStoreId = getCurrentBaseStoreId();
        final String catalogId = getCurrentProductCatalogId();

        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(baseStoreId) && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(catalogId))
        {
            return baseStoreId + "-" + catalogId;
        }

        return DEFAULT_CART_IDENTIFIER_COOKIE_NAME;
    }

    protected String getCurrentBaseStoreId()
    {
        final BaseStoreModel baseStore = baseStoreService.getCurrentBaseStore();
        return baseStore == null ? StringUtils.EMPTY : baseStore.getUid();
    }

    protected String getCurrentProductCatalogId()
    {
        for (final CatalogVersionModel catalogVersionModel : catalogVersionService.getSessionCatalogVersions())
        {
            if (!((catalogVersionModel.getCatalog() instanceof ContentCatalogModel) || (catalogVersionModel
                    .getCatalog() instanceof ClassificationSystemModel)))
            {
                return catalogVersionModel.getCatalog().getId();
            }
        }
        return StringUtils.EMPTY;
    }
}
```

The content of the `jsp` page is not really that important since it can be empty and this behaviour still happens. I do not know exactly what could be the root of this. Is there any effective way to debug such issues?

Comment: That `CMSItemNotFoundException`, are you doing anything with it if it's thrown? Have you tried actually catching it inside the method itself and see what causes it? Also, is the debugger telling you nothing useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a usual bug when creating B2B Sites. A workaround is to open the /smartedit and login to your site from there. Hybris will create a proper session and you should be able to open the site.

Possible long time solution:
If you are creating a B2B site, check spring-filter-config.xml in your Storefront extension and check this section. It should look like this:

```
    <alias name="b2cAcceleratorSiteChannels" alias="acceleratorSiteChannels"/>
    <util:set id="b2cAcceleratorSiteChannels" value-type="de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.enums.SiteChannel">
        <ref bean="SiteChannel.B2C"/>
        <ref bean="SiteChannel.B2B"/>
    </util:set>
```

You can remove the SiteChannel.B2C if everything is fine

Comment: No luck. I made sure `spring-filter-config.xml` looks as you said, but with no luck, the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this behaviour was due to a bad argument when importing an impex related to this page:

```
INSERT_UPDATE PageTemplate;$contentCV[unique = true];uid[unique = true];name;frontendTemplateName;restrictedPageTypes(code);active[default = true]
;;CartPageTemplate;Cart Page Template;"cartPage";ContentPage;false;
```

should've been

```
INSERT_UPDATE PageTemplate;$contentCV[unique = true];uid[unique = true];name;frontendTemplateName;restrictedPageTypes(code);active[default = true]
;;CartPageTemplate;Cart Page Template;"cart/cartPage";ContentPage;false;
```

Replacing `"cartPage"` with `"cart/cartPage"` did all the magic.